# UDP on Android emulator

Tags: android, proxy, udp, client-server

I'm trying to establish a simple UDP connection between a client program running on an android emulator and a server, on two different systems. The server side is fine, but the client side keeps crashing. Is it a problem with the emulator? Should i redirect the port to make it work?

CLIENT SIDE (on android emulator):

```
package com.example.clientrecv;   
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.net.DatagramPacket;  
import java.net.DatagramSocket;  
import java.net.SocketException;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.Toast;  


public class MainActivity extends Activity  
{  
public String text;  
public int serverport=1234;  
public byte[] message=new byte[1000];  
public Button b;  
public DatagramPacket p;  
public DatagramSocket s;  
public Toast t;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                try {
                    p = new DatagramPacket(message,message.length);
                    s = new DatagramSocket(serverport); 
                    try {
                        s.receive(p);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    text= new String(message,0,p.getLength());
                    Log.d("hello","the message:"+text);
                    s.close();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

}   
}
                public void showmsg()
                {
                    t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }  
}  


SERVER SIDE: (on pc)  


import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
class serversend  
{  
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception  
  {
String strmsg="Server says hello";
int serverport=1234;
int len=strmsg.length();
System.out.println("starting");
byte[] message=strmsg.getBytes();
try{
InetAddress local=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
DatagramSocket s=new DatagramSocket();
DatagramPacket p=new DatagramPacket(message,len,local,serverport); 
System.out.println("Running");
s.send(p);
System.out.println("Sent");
}catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("caught");
} 
  }  
}
```

Comment: have you defined the port for communication between client and server ?

Comment: yes. but i have no idea how to make it communicate. is it even possible?

Comment: i even tried redirecting it with the following commands:           telnet localhost 5554
redir add udp:<sourceport>:<destport>

Answer (score 0):

There are many example available that can help you to communicate between server and client using UDP
to communicate between these two should add the client port on server side

```
InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102");
```

here are the Following Link For Client Server Communication Using UDP 
[LINK UDP1](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/)
[Link UDP2](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html)

Comment: These should be on the client side, right? and the code works with normal UDP with java. but i'm not able to run it on an emulator.

Comment: have you gone through the given link ? 
is it not showing the appropriate result? any crash warning ?  if so then add log cat along with your question

Comment: yeah, i went through. the emulator said "the application has stopped"

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
have you defined your class in manifest file ?

Comment: and i tried to paste my code here. but it wants too many format specifications to be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Android after 3.0 version doesn't allow you to implement networking operations within the main UI Thread. You must define a new Thread for that... Here is how you can do it:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          //here you Set up you parameters and launch the thread (e.g):

          this.newThread = new Thread(new mThread());
      this.newThread.start();


      /* Next you define your newThread's run method in wich all networking 
         operations must take place*/


   class mThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

      // Do all networking tasks you need                                               

           }
        }
```